# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using firebase database to store the data and I am mounting the data using the useEffect hook. But it gives me warning of missing dependency arrays.

Whenever I pass dependencies it goes into an infinite loop

```
const Channels = props => {
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
  const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let loadedChannels = [];

    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("channels")
      .on("child_added", snap => {
        loadedChannels.push(snap.val());
        setChannels(channels.concat(loadedChannels));
        setFirstLoad(true);
      });
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Have you check that depency does not change when the useEffect is triggered? that way it will trigger the useEffect again. In a infinite lop

Comment: UseEffect has channels dependency which continuously changes inside it whenever I set Channels using setChannels(). That's why I don't pass channels as a dependency.

Comment: `But it gives me warning of missing dependency arrays` What dependencies are missing?

Comment: try using callback-based setter like `setChannels(({ channels}) => ({channels: channels.concat(loadedChannels) }));`(not really sure, that's why did not put an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Looking at it again, the reason you're getting that error is because you're closing over the initial value of `channels` when your `useEffect()` runs the first time. So `channels` really should be in your dependency array because when that value changes, you would want the new value to be reflected in the state updates from then on. You're sort of trying to get around it with the `loadedChannels` array which is a weird anti-pattern.

I would actually recommend that you tweak it to something like this. Note how `setChannels` is now called with a function, which takes the *actual up to date value of `channels`* as an argument and lets you update the value without it being out of date due to a closure.

Note also how the `useEffect()` function returns *another* function that removes the Firebase event listener when the component unmounts!

```
const Channels = props => {
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
  const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function onFirebaseUpdate(snap) {
      setChannels((previousChannelsValue) => {
        return previousChannelsValue.concat(snap.val())
      });
      setFirstLoad(true);
    }

    firebase
      .database()
      .ref("channels")
      .on("child_added", onFirebaseUpdate);

    // You'll want to remove this listener when the component unmounts...
    return function() {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref("channels")
        .off("child_added", onFirebaseUpdate);
    }
  }, []);
}
```

If you still get a warning, it's probably because either `firebase` or `setChannels` are references in the function and should be considered for addition to the dependency array. But in this case you (hopefully) know what you're doing and what's going on and can ignore the warning.

Comment: Thank you so much for the above solution. It works for me

Comment: @AnjuBudhwan if it works for you please upvote and accept the answer! :)